# Atom Editor Scrolls When I Click On A Line of Code

Tags: scroll, editor, line, atom-editor, pane

recently when I have been using Atom Editor, when I click on a line of code the editor scrolls in so that the code that I clicked on is in the center of the window (if that makes sense). For example if I have 100 lines of code, if I click on the code in line 25, it will automatically put line 25 in the middle of my screen. I think the catalyst for it was when I opened up a second file and dragged it into a pane next to my other file, so that I was editing two files at once side by side. It makes it hard to navigate through my code. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Update: When I click above the middle of the window, it scrolls upward and highlights as it scrolls, when I click below it does the same but scrolls downward. Is it a mouse issue?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the answer to my problem. I had downloaded a package named "Typewriter Scroll" that is supposed to emulate a typewriter. I disabled it and my code no longer scrolls when I click.